# How can I check whether a python xarray Dataset/DataArray object is loaded into memory, or still points to data on disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, ipython, python-xarray

The `xarray` package in python seems to use "lazy loading" to point to structured data on the disk (e.g. netCDF, HDF5), then [loads the data into memory](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.load.html) only "when necessary." How can I check whether a given Dataset or DataArray object in an interactive python session or in a python script is actually "loaded?"

Ideally, something like

```
import xarray as xr
dataset = xr.open_dataset('data.nc') 
dataset.is_loaded() # is it loaded into memory?
```

Not sure if this is a meaningful question, but want to be able to safely and confidently control this behavior for giant datasets, so the whole file doesn't get unnecessarily read.

Comment: I actually don't think this is possible in xarray at the moment using public API. @shoyer would have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't currently possible using the public API. This information *is* available using private APIs. If you look at `DataArray.variable._data` with an array loaded from disk, you'll see a `MemoryCachedArray` object (as of xarray v0.9) if it's being cached:

```
>>> xarray.DataArray([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).to_netcdf('foo.nc')
>>> array = xarray.open_dataarray('foo.nc')
>>> array.variable._data
MemoryCachedArray(array=CopyOnWriteArray(array=LazilyIndexedArray(array=ScipyArrayWrapper(array=array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int32)), key=(slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None)))))
```

If your data is large enough that you're concerned about caching being problematic, I definitely recommend opening any files with `cache=False`, e.g., `xarray.open_dataarray('foo.nc', cache=False)`. In that case, you won't see the `MemoryCachedArray` object in `_data`:

```
>>> array.variable._data
CopyOnWriteArray(array=LazilyIndexedArray(array=ScipyArrayWrapper(array=array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int32)), key=(slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))))
```

If you still think you need to be able to check whether caching is possible on existing xarray objects, please raise an issue on our GitHub page to discuss potential new API.

Comment: Cool, thanks! So if I use `cache=False`, will the data refrain from being loaded until I call `.load()` on the Dataset or DataArray slice (for example, I have a NetCDF with 20 variables and 1000 time steps, but want to create a DataArray from just 1 variable at 1 time step)? And what if I try to, for example, multiply a DataArray by 2 after loading it with `DataArray`? Will that operation still force loading into memory, or will it raise an error?

`xarray` is amazing and incredibly useful by the way.

Comment: That's right, indexing is lazy even with `cache=False`. Multiplication is not lazy, unless you're using dask.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can check whether your dataset was chunked or not by `dataset.chunks`. Based on that, you can construct function detecting whether your dataset was loaded or not, e.g.:

```
def is_loaded(chunks):
   out = False
   if chunks is not None:
      out = True
   return out
print(is_loaded(dataset.chunks))
```

Comment: This will not work. Xarray uses lazy loading regardless of whether a dataset is chunked using dask.